# What can I do to give the swords proper lighting?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I've changed the position of the lighting to various places, but I still get this type of image when rendered, where the swords are dark and you can see the decimation on the glass sword. I'm having issues figuring out the lighting, what can I do to improve the quality of the render?

[image: Lighting and camera setup]

[image]

[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: It's the "topology", the way that the vertices are connected by edges and faces, and you need to change the mesh, not the lighting.  In general, decimation is not a good way to reduce vertex count, but here, you might be happy enough with a decimation on unsubdivide with one more iteration than you used.  Reducing vertex count is generally done with manual retopology (search "blender retopo tutorial") but here, you could get away with automated solutions, like Exoside Quad Remesher.